# Who is my localhost win7 - it's a bit funny

Tags: windows, localhost

I got a localhost service on my machine, but I don't remember installing it lol.

And now that I am really need it, I can't figure out who is running this service... It's just  a simple page of "It works!".

Been trying searching my win7 for "It works!" keyword but found nothing. And all the index.html files seems to be not it. So it's really funny now...

Anyway I can find it out?

**Edit:**
This is the my localhost icon [image: local host icon], I even search it on Google images without any result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Collabnet Subversion Edge installed on your machine.  This brings along it's own customised setup of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Find the folder c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourservice, if you are using the iis to host your services.

Comment: no its not apache and its not IIs, I just don't know who it is... lol

Comment: Sorry but, it is a few informations to help...

Comment: Check your hosts file to make sure localhost isn't pointing somewhere it shouldn't be.  I thought "It works!" was Apache or nGinx.  Can't remember which.

Comment: Look: http://www.ohloh.net/p/svnedge-discovery/managers